# Controlling Placement of Label with AxisObject[]: Need it further below second axis

Tags: plotting, axeslabel

I'm trying to plot a second x axis *below* the first using `AxisObject[]` and `Placed[]` within the `Epilog[]` of a plot.  My goal is to have the label for this second axis centered and below the axis.

The problem is that I can't get `Placed[]` to put it where I want (below the axis far enough that it doesn't cover the axis tick and tick labels as it does in the second example below.

Here's my code

```
tmp = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1},
   Frame -> True,
   ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {160, Automatic}}
   ];

Show[tmp, 
 Epilog -> {AxisObject[Line[{{0, -0.5}, {1, -0.5}}],
    AxisLabel -> 
     Placed["Second Axis Label: {Center, -1}", {Center, -1}]]}]

Show[tmp, 
 Epilog -> {AxisObject[Line[{{0, -0.5}, {1, -0.5}}],
    AxisLabel -> Placed["Second Axis Label: Center", Center]]}]
```

[image: Placed with {Center, -1}]

[image: Placed with Center]

BTW, I'm running Mathematica 13.0 on Ubuntu/MATE 22.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Placed[expr,{pos,epos}] specifies that position epos in expr should be placed at relative position pos.`

```
Show[tmp, 
 Epilog -> {AxisObject[Line[{{0, -0.5}, {1, -0.5}}],
    AxisLabel -> Placed[
    "Second Axis Label: Center", {0.5,{0.5,3}}]]}]
```

[image]